# Удаление элементов по кругу

Tags: c#, .net

Есть задача: по кругу стоят от 1 до N человек. Идя по кругу надо вычеркивать каждого второго, пока не останется один и, соответственно, вывести его в консоль. Программа должна работать с классами List и LinkedList (обращаться напрямую по индексу к элементу нельзя).

Метод для удаления должен быть общий для List и LinkedList.
В метод я передаю `IEnumerable<T> ie`, но у него нет метода Remove.
Пытался создать объект `ICollection<T>` - кидает ошибку.

Как грамотно реализовать метод, чтобы работал и для `List<T>`, и для `LinkedList<T>`?

```
public static void RemoveEachSecondItem<T>(IEnumerable<T> ie)
    {
        ICollection<T> ic = new ICollection<T>(ie);
        while (ie.Count() > 1)
        {
            bool isOdd = false;//четный элемент
            foreach (var item in ic)
            {
                if (isOdd)
                {
                    ic.Remove(item);
                }

            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Посмотрите в сторону такой структуры данных: [Кольцевой односвязанный список](https://metanit.com/sharp/algoritm/2.7.php) - решение будет достаточно простым.

Comment: `В метод я передаю IEnumerable<T> ie, но у него нет метода Remove.` - это часть условия задачи или можно заменить на `ICollection<T>`? Для List, LinkedList и других коллекций это равнозначная замена т.к. `ICollection<T>` включает `IEnumerable<T>`

Answer (score 6):

**"Честный" вариант решения**

Алгоритм, по идее, прост:

- Cтроим [кольцевой односвязный список](https://metanit.com/sharp/algoritm/2.7.php) (как упомянуто в комментарии [@A K](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/213987/a-k)) по исходному перечислению (`IEnumerable`) элементов
- Пока элементов в построенном списке больше одного, идём по нему и удаляем каждый четный элемент
- Возвращаем единственный оставшийся в списке элемент

Реализация может получиться сложнее или проще... Пример:

Узел списка:

```
private class MyNode<T>
{
    public readonly T item;
    public MyNode<T> next;

    public MyNode(T item)
    {
        this.item = item;
    }
}
```

Построение списка по перечислению элементов:

- Храним ссылки на первый и предыдущий узлы

  - Ссылка на первый узел нужна для его особой обработки: мы не можем на первой итерации цикла последнему узлу проставить в качестве следующего первый (мы не знаем ещё ничего про последний узел), поэтому для этого по-особому обрабатываем первый узел в цикле и делаем недостающую связку "последний -> первый" после цикла
  - Ссылка на предыдущий узел нужна, чтобы на итерации цикла (кроме первой) предыдущему узлу в качестве следующего проставить текущий, тем самым создавая односвязный список с направлением "вперёд"
- Проходим по исходному перечислению, по-особому обрабатывая первый узел и проставляя связь между предыдущим и текущим для остальных узлов
- Закольцовываем список, указывая последнему элементу (после цикла `previousNode` как раз указывает на него) в качестве следующего первый
- Возвращаем первый узел - его достаточно для работы со списком

_

```
private static MyNode<T> CreateCircularList<T>(IEnumerable<T> ie)
{
    MyNode<T> firstNode = null;
    MyNode<T> previousNode = null;
    foreach (var item in ie)
    {
        var newNode = new MyNode<T>(item);
        if (firstNode == null)
        {
            firstNode = newNode;
        }
        else
        {
            previousNode.next = newNode;
        }
        previousNode = newNode;
    }
    previousNode.next = firstNode;
    return firstNode;
}
```

Непосредственно само удаление элементов:

- Считаем пустое перечисление элементов недопустимым вариантом
- Создаём список и получаем ссылку на первый узел
- Создаём флаг (`isOdd`), отвечающий за удаление каждого второго узла (`== true` - удалять, `== false` - нет)
- В качестве текущего (рассматриваемого) узла первоначально берём первый
- Ссылка на предыдущий узел нужна для "склеивания" предыдущего и следующего при удалении текущего
- Пока узлов в списке больше одного:

  - Если узел нужно удалить (он второй/"четный") - склеиваем предыдущий со следующим, тем самым исключая текущий узел из списка, и уменьшаем счетчик количества узлов в списке на единицу
  - Иначе в качестве предыдущего узла устанавливаем текущий, плавно готовясь к следующей итерации цикла, в которой этот самый предыдущий узел понадобится для "склеивания"
  - После чего переходим к следующему узлу и меняем значение флага
- В итоге возвращаем значение единственного оставшегося узла

_

```
public static T RemoveEachSecondItem<T>(IEnumerable<T> ie)
{
    var elementsCount = ie.Count();
    if (elementsCount == 0)
        throw new Exception("Empty ie");

    var firstNode = CreateCircularList(ie);
    var isOdd = false;
    var currentNode = firstNode;
    MyNode<T> previousNode = null;
    while (elementsCount > 1)
    {
        if (isOdd)
        {
            previousNode.next = currentNode.next;
            elementsCount--;
        }
        else
        {
            previousNode = currentNode;
        }
        currentNode = currentNode.next;
        isOdd = !isOdd;
    }
    return currentNode.item;
}
```

---

**"Нечестный" вариант решения**

- Посчитать сразу индекс элемента, который останется. Доказательства приведённой формулы (из количества элементов вычитаем ближайшую снизу степень двойки, после чего разность умножаем на два - получаем нужный индекс) у меня нет, но она работает
- Вернуть элемент по этому индексу. Из-за условий задачи для этого придётся воспользоваться foreach-ем

Пример:

```
public static T RemoveEachSecondItemShort<T>(IEnumerable<T> ie)
{
    var elementsCount = ie.Count();
    var powOfTwo = 1;
    while (powOfTwo <= elementsCount)
    {
        powOfTwo <<= 1;
    }
    powOfTwo >>= 1;
    var requiredElementIndex = (elementsCount - powOfTwo) * 2;
    var index = 0;
    foreach (var element in ie)
    {
        if (index == requiredElementIndex)
            return element;

        index++;
    }
    throw new Exception("Empty ie");
}
```

Comment: А я тут накропал другой вариант: в нём нет допструктур, чистое итерирование IEnumerable. Правда варианты даёт другие, чем ваш ответ, потому что я вырезаю начиная с первого.

Comment: @AK вырезать по условию задачи всё-таки надо элементы с индексами 1, 3 и т.д. Насчет вариант с чистым `IEnumerable` - а в чём он состоит? В Java в итераторе есть метод `remove`, а тут я смог допереть только до упомянутого вами списка. Не считая "нечестный" вариант, конечно

Comment: @Regent, а почему класс приватный?

Comment: @Илья потому же что и метод `CreateCircularList` - это вспомогательные внутренние вещи, которым нет смысла "торчать" во внешний мир. Предполагается, что это всё находится внутри одного public-класса

Comment: @Илья а вообще, кстати, алгоритм и особенно реализация первого варианта понятны? Код, на мой взгляд, получился относительно сложным в понимании - возможно, нужно расписать в ответе детали реализации

Comment: @Regent, ну, если сильно не углубляться, то я  понимаю, что происходит.
Однако, буду благодарен за более детальное объяснение

Comment: По сути это задача "Считалка Иосифа Флавия" (https://habr.com/company/goto/blog/351092/), если представить N как 2^A+L, где A — наибольшее возможное, то ответом будет 2*L+1 (или 2*L, если у нас индексы с 0)

Comment: @Илья расписал в ответе формирование списка и само удаление

Answer (score 3):

1. Вам в код(в цикл foreach) нужно добавить изменение переменной isOdd, ибо сейчас это выглядит как просто foreach, в котором никогда не вызывается Remove.

**Сейчас он:** isOdd == false постоянно. Когда мы в foreach делаем if(isOdd == true), это никогда не произойдет

**Как можно сделать:** Сначала он true(при инициализация. В начале цикла он меняется на противоположный(получается первый элемент нечетный, а второй четный. И таким образом происходит переключение).

2. `while (ie.Count() > 1)`

что вы хотите получить от этого куска кода? ie.Count() будет возвращать одно и то же, ибо когда вы делаете это `ICollection<T> ic = new ICollection<T>(ie);` вы получаете копию, а не работаете с той же коллекцией [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В итоге когда закончится цикл foreach, вы выйдете в цикл while иии... он будет крутится вечно). 
Если я правильно понял идею, вам нужно заменить `while (ie.Count() > 1)` на `while (ic.Count() > 1)`

3. `ICollection<T> ic = new ICollection<T>(ie);` нельзя создавать объект интерфейса. Ибо интерфейс - лишь декларация, описание того как можно работать с чем то. Он не имеет ни строчки реализации и не может. Вы можете создать(инстанцировать) только объект определенного класса.

Например `ICollection<T> ic = new List<T>(ie);`

тут мы говорим, что я создаю объект класс `List<T>`, но работать с ним буду через интерфейс `ICollection<T>`.

4. Вы не можете изменять коллекцию внутри цикла foreach(спасибо @aa_talanin. Как я такое мог забыть). Используйте не foreach, а цикл for. Но т.к. нельзя использовать цикл for...Стоит записывать элементы, который вы хотите удалить в отдельный список, а потом в цикле делать Remove из первой коллекции.

Comment: могу ошибаться, но вроде бы внутри foreach нельзя изменять перечисляемую коллекцию

Comment: по поводу 2 пункта: компилятор не может создать ic
выдается ошибка создания экземпляра интерфейса «ICollection <T>»

Comment: @Илья обновил ответ

Answer (score 3):

По сути ваша задача — ["Считалка Иосифа Флавия"](https://habr.com/company/goto/blog/351092/)

И если у нас на входе N элементов, то нужно найти такое максимальное целое A, чтобы N = 2<sup>A</sup>+L, где L ⩾ 0. Тогда результатом будет элемент под индексом 2L (индексы с 0).

Поскольку, по условию на входе могут быть `List<T>` или `LinkedList<T>`, которые реализуют `ICollection<T>`, можно написать такое простое решение:

```
T FlaviusRoulette<T>(ICollection<T> source)
{
    int c = source.Count, n = 0;
    while (1 << n <= c) ++n;
    return source.ElementAt(2 * c - (1 << n));
}
```

Если же вы хотите, чтобы метод работал для любых `IEnumerable<T>` — выхода нет, придется закешировать все элементы, т. к. любой может оказаться ответом:

```
T FlaviusRoulette<T>(IEnumerable<T> source)
{
    var col = source as ICollection<T> ?? source.ToList();
    int c = col.Count, n = 0;
    while (1 << n <= c) ++n;
    return col.ElementAt(2 * c - (1 << n));
}
```

Проверка:

```
Console.WriteLine(FlaviusRoulette(Enumerable.Range(1, 41))); // 19
```

<sub>Проверку `source == null` и `source.Count == 0` оставляю на ТС.</sub>

Comment: Вспомнил ещё про условие из задачи: _"обращаться напрямую по индексу к элементу нельзя"_. Странное оно, конечно, - единичное прохождение foreach-ем с отдельным индексом ничуть не лучше (а порой и хуже) `ElementAt` и занимает немало строк кода

Comment: @Regent, я подозреваю это условие там введено из-за того, что `LinkedList` не реализует `IList`, поэтому у него нет индексатора. `ElementAt` запускает `foreach` для таких последовательностей. В любом случае, главное в ответе — показать минимальное понятное решение, а "подгонять" его под ограничения преподавателя (или интервьювера) я предлагаю автору самостоятельно.

Answer (score 2):

Можно пожертвовать памятью и получить быстрое и довольно простое решение:

```
T RemoveEachSecondItem<T>(IEnumerable<T> source)
{
    List<T> src = source.ToList();
    List<T> tgt = new List<T>(src.Count / 2);   
    foreach(var item in source)
        src.Add(item);
    bool isRemoved = false;
    while(src.Count > 1)
    {
        foreach(T item in src)
        {
            if(!isRemoved)
                tgt.Add(item);
            isRemoved = !isRemoved;
        }
        List<T> temp = src;
        src = tgt;
        tgt = temp;
        tgt.Clear();
    }
    return src.FirstOrDefault();
}

//Пример использования
Console.WriteLine(RemoveEachSecondItem<int>(Enumerable.Range(1, 7), false));
```

**Достоинства:**

- работать будет с любым перечислением.
- хорошо оптимизируется для эффективного использования кэша процессора, за счет использования линейных массивов, на которых строится `List<T>`.

**Недостатки:**

- дополнительный расход памяти (N*2,5+x с учетом хранения исходных данных входного перечисления или N*1,5+x, если исходные данные не хранятся в памяти процесса, а генерируются например, где x - разница между реальной и используемой емкостями `src`)
- при материализации перечисления будет происходить постепенное увеличение емкости `src` со всеми вытекающими накладными расходами.

Comment: Дважды вызывается `source.Count()`, потом `foreach` по `source`. Это не проблема, если на входе `List` или `LinkedList`, но если на входе будет генерируемый каждый раз заново `enumerable`, то это очень неэффективно. В коде @Regent'а такие же недостатки. Я не придираюсь, просто интересно, можно ли обойтись всего одним проходом по входной коллекции.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov да, меня тоже это смутило. Но если убрать Count(), то получим оверхед на ресайзе листа. Даже не знаю что хуже...

Comment: Да, я тоже ломаю голову, как бы красиво избавиться от ресайза.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov Проще всего было бы в параметрах вместо IEnumerable <T> указать ICollection<T>, тогда проблема сама пропадет, но автор не указал, можно ли это или IEnumerable<T> часть условия.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov что уж прям "очень неэффективно"... У меня в обоих вариантах по одному Count-у и одному foreach-у. 2*N - это всё-таки не N^2 и даже не 100*N. Причем в "честном" варианте можно избавиться от Count-а (достаточно посчитать кол-во элементов в самом foreach-е) - Count там присутствует только для того, чтобы код был короче/красивее/понятнее

Comment: *не генерирует лишних объектов в процессе работы* — списки не считаются? Лучше уж тогда проверять, если у нас `source is ICollection<T>`, то брать `Count`, иначе — не брать...

Comment: @rdorn основные споры в этом вопросе идут, конечно, вокруг алгоритмов и их реализации, но позволю себе заметить, что `RemoveOdd` - на мой взгляд, неудачное название параметра (почему, кстати, с заглавной буквы?). В моём представлении "удалять четный? Да/Нет" подразумевает, что либо мы удаляем четный элемент, либо не удаляем его

Comment: @Regent - а вдруг на входе такой enumerable, в котором на каждой итерации происходит обращение в БД или любая другая длительная операция? Это я так, теоретизирую.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov да, это возможно. Однако один раз эти длительные операции всё равно выполнятся - ждать придётся в любом случае. С точки зрения сложности алгоритма ведь что N, что 2*N - одно и то же. С точки зрения реальности - если для кого-то это будет критично (1 или 2 секунды - это уже действительно ощутимо), придётся-таки модифицировать код. Но так как мой ответ после добавления пояснений к реализации уже раздулся до 3 экранов, то вряд ли добавлять в него ещё и вариант с одним проходом - хорошая идея. В решении же из данного ответа вроде Count-ы можно просто удалить

Comment: @АндрейNOP листы - это рабочие объекты, а не лишние, ресайз в них не происходит, так что мусор они не генерят. И да, их как было 2 в начале, так и остается до конца работы.

Comment: @Regent по поводу `RemoveOdd` - есть вариант лучше? я не придумал, плохо у меня с неймингом для учебно-демонстрационных задач

Comment: @rdorn с флагом нормальных идей нет: вариант `removeOddNotEven` вроде крайне далёк от идеала. В голову лезут варианты с передачей enum-а или int-a - там можно отталкиваться от общего названия четности. В принципе, если идей особых нет, можно и плюнуть на это - сиё ведь несущественно для задачи

Comment: Правка `int count = source.Count();` => `int count = source is ICollection ? ((ICollection)source).Count : source.Count();` ровным счетом ничего не дает ([ссылка](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#system.core/system/linq/Enumerable.cs,1314)). Я имел ввиду, если `source` не реализует `ICollection`, то не использовать конструктор с `capacity`, а сразу вызывать `new List<T>(source)`, ну и при массовой вставке `AddRange` может быть эффективнее (хотя если `capacity` уже известен, то — нет) Ну и, наконец, проверка на `Collection` есть внутри конструктора `List` (не хватает места для ссылки)

Comment: Т.е. в итоге первые 5 строк в вашем методе можно заменить на `List<T> src = new List<T>(source); List<T> tgt = new List<T>(src.Count % 2);` ничего при этом не потеряв. (Кстати, почему `% 2`, а не `/ 2`?)

Comment: @АндрейNOP Можно ещё немного проще, 'source.ToList()', поправлю чуть позже. за деление спасибо, тупнул, конечно '/'